# Auto load de vários diretórios

Tags: php, php-autoload

Eu tenho estas funções:

core/init.php:

```
...
spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
   require_once ('libs/'.$class.'.php');
});
---
```

controllers/Images_Controller.php

```
require_once "core/init.php";
require_once "models/Image.php";
require_once "models/User.php";

class Images_Controller extends Controller {
   ...
}
```

Sendo que as libs são algumas classes que vou precisar ao longo do programa, ou seja, vou precisar de requisitar as libs sem dúvida, mas também vou precisar de requisitar os models que preciso, isto é um modelo mvc, os *paths* são em relação ao index.
A minha questão é: como é que faço, dentro do `core/init.php`, que o programa faça *load* TAMBÉM dos models à medida que os vou instanciando?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
  if(file_exists('libs/'.$class.'.php') {
   require_once ('libs/'.$class.'.php');
  } elseif(file_exists('models/'.$class.'.php') {
   require_once ('models/'.$class.'.php');
  }
});
```

Além do mais que não recomendo utilizar este forma a inclusão de dependências.

Conhece composer? Recomendo deixar a cargo dele fazer o seu class map.

https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#psr-0

Abraços!

Comment: Porque não recomenda? Obrigado funcionou

Comment: Justamente por ser uma tecnologia antiga. Hoje em dia temos o composer, um ótimo gerenciador de dependências, recomendo pesquisar sobre.